# Change default page for subdomain?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add a subdomain and I would like it to display a different default page than my site would without a subdomain.  So `mysite.com` displays `index.html` by default.  I would like `sub.mysite.com` to display `sub.html`.

I am able to get my nginx server to handle the subdomain requests with the setup below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com sub.mysite.com;
```

But it just goes to the default page for the main site.  How can I tell nginx that if the subdomain is used it needs to return a specific HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `server` block for your new subdomain.